# Java isFile returns false even when file exists

Tags: java, file-io

I have a file on Linux:

```
[root@localhost ~]# touch /tmp/test.txt
[root@localhost ~]# ls -l /tmp/test.txt
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Jul  6 11:44 /tmp/test.txt
```

And I have the following Java code:

```
File f = new File("/tmp/test.txt");
System.out.print(f.isFile());
```

For some reason, the output is always false.  Why is that?

Based on my understanding, the file is a regular file and the directory is readable by all.  It's not clear to me why it returns false.

Comment: the file is not considered *normal* by JVM

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25039156/java-what-constitutes-a-normal-file-in-the-context-of-file-isfile

Comment: Try accessing the file using its absolute path.

Comment: File is owned by root user/group... Is your java code running as root as well? I'm not sure if this can cause the issue that you are facing.

Comment: The above example works perfectly for me. Returning `true` even if the file is owned by root.

Comment: @sinclair I read through the thread but I don't see how this applies to my situation.  /tmp has "x" on all users.  The file is a regular file.

Comment: The file has a SELinux security context. What does `ls -Z /tmp/test.txt` say?

Comment: @thatotherguy  I don't think so: `[root@localhost ~]# ls -Z /tmp/test.txt
-rw-r--r--. root root unconfined_u:object_r:user_tmp_t:s0 /tmp/test.txt`

Comment: @GuilhermeP My Java code is SSH-ing to the server as root.

Comment: Anything you do with `File` will apply to the client filesystem, not the server's.

Comment: @thatotherguy You mean it's looking for that path on my client filesystem?

Comment: Yes. You can verify by creating a `/tmp/test.txt` on your client and see whether the test now returns true

Comment: @thatotherguy I think you are right.  That explains it.  Thanks!

Comment: `.` is the clue. Voting to reopen this.

Comment: "Following the file mode bits is a single character that specifies
     whether an alternate access method such as an access control list
     applies to the file.  When the character following the file mode
     bits is a space, there is no alternate access method.  When it is a
     printing character, then there is such a method.

     GNU ‘ls’ uses a ‘.’ character to indicate a file with a security
     context, but no other alternate access method."

Comment: @PLui Did this thread had a solution in the end ? (I have the same issue with files containing special characters)

Answer (score 0):

if and only if the file denoted by this abstract pathname exists and is a normal file, false otherwise.

so what is a `normal file`? Any non-directory file created by a Java application is guaranteed to be a normal file or satisfies other system-dependent criteria.

so do not use this function. you could use `File.exists` and `!File.isDirectory` to achieve this function.